# Unable to send a variable from content script to popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I've been struggling with passing "getVideo" from `content.js` (my content script) to `popup.js`. Right now I copied from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging just to try to get a message. However, as soon as the page opens, I get an error on the console: `Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined`. I've tried every single suggestion/answer from every thread related to Chrome extension messaging with nothing working. This makes me believe I have something more wrong with how I have the extension set up, but I have no idea what. Thanks!

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "JW Player Tools",
  "description": "This extension lets you speed up and download captions from a JW video",
  "version": "1.2.5",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
 {
   "matches": ["*://*.tower.la.utexas.edu/*"],
   "all_frames": true,
   "js": ["content.js"],
   "run_at": "document_idle"
 }]
}
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });



    var playback = document.getElementById('playback');
    playback.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var newspeed = prompt("Current Speed: " + getVideo.playbackRate + "\nNew Speed: ");
        getVideo.playbackRate = newspeed;
    });

    var captions = document.getElementById('captions');
    captions.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (index = 0; index < getVideo.textTracks[0].cues.length; ++index) {
            document.write(getVideo.textTracks[0].cues[index].text + " ");
        }
    });
});
```

content.js

```
var waitForVideo = setInterval(checkForElement, 150);

function checkForElement() {
    var videoElem = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    if (videoElem.length) {
        clearInterval(waitForVideo);
        var videolink = videoElem[0].getAttribute('src');
        getVideo = videoElem[0];



        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
        });




    }
}
```

popup.html

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>JW Tools</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button id="playback">Speed Up</button>
        <button id="captions">Download Captions</button>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Please provide your *popup.html* and HTML for the web page on which you are testing this (or at least a URL).

Comment: It is a Bad Idea™ to use the name *background.js* as the name of your content script. It is too easy to confuse with it being a background script.

Comment: In your content script, `getVideo` is a DOM element. You will not be able to send it in a message. DOM elements are not JSON-serializable. All messages must be JSON-serializable. You don't actually show trying to send it as a message, but you say in your first sentence that it is what you are struggling with.

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes regarding name and missing info.

I was not aware I couldn't send DOM element through message, though it makes sense. However, I still need to get that DOM element into popup.js somehow (unless I can move the functions from popup.js to content.js?) Could you guide me on that? @Makyen 

Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need to pass the element itself, just the text data: extract it and send it. Also, you might need to use proper DOM manipulation or insertAdjacentHTML instead of document.write.

Comment: @umer936, We can advise, but as wOxxOm implied, part of that advice is you might only need some portion of the info that is contained within the DOM element you are wanting to message, which you can extract and message, or move processing into the content script. We don't know what you need from the element, so can't give detailed advice. However, assuming the code you have provided duplicates the problem described in the question (I have not yet tried it), getting that information is actually a different problem, and should be a separate Question. I'll try the code and comment again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I moved the functions to content.js like so.

content.js

```
var waitForVideo = setInterval(checkForElement, 150);

function checkForElement() {
    var videoElem = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    if (videoElem.length) {
        clearInterval(waitForVideo);
        getVideo = videoElem[0];
    }
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.task == "caption") {
        for (index = 0; index < getVideo.textTracks[0].cues.length; ++index) {
            document.write(getVideo.textTracks[0].cues[index].text + " ");
        }
    } else if (request.task == "speed") {
        var newspeed = prompt("Current Speed: " + getVideo.playbackRate + "\nNew Speed: ");
        getVideo.playbackRate = newspeed;
    } else {
        // sendResponse({});
    } 
});
```

and used popup.js to message content.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var playback = document.getElementById('playback');
    playback.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // var newspeed = prompt("Current Speed: " + getVideo.playbackRate + "\nNew Speed: ");
        // getVideo.playbackRate = newspeed;

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {
                task: "speed"
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response.farewell);
            });
        });

    });

    var captions = document.getElementById('captions');
    captions.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // for (index = 0; index < getVideo.textTracks[0].cues.length; ++index) {
        // document.write(getVideo.textTracks[0].cues[index].text + " ");
        // }

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {
                task: "caption"
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response.farewell);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help! @Makyen @wOxxOm